# Proof that the infinity of all continuous functions is greater than the infinity of reals

Tags: functions, infinity

I've been trying to prove the above statement and found the below link in the course of my research.

[Proof that the set of all possible curves is of cardinality $\aleph_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078067/proof-that-the-set-of-all-possible-curves-is-of-cardinality-aleph-2)

However, I do not understand part of the explanation provided by Eric Wofsey, and I attach a screenshot of this part below.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIkS9.png)

If anybody could help me understand this, I would be grateful.

Tia,

Yang

Comment: The number of curves is **not** greater than the number number of reals, as Eric Wofsey explains.  Can you be more specific about what part of his explanation you don't understand?

Comment: Building on the saulspatz comment (since there may be ambiguity about the definition of "curve"): It sounds like you are claiming that the cardinality of continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is strictly larger than the cardinality of the real numbers, and this is not true.  This is because _continuous_ functions can be characterized by their values on the rationals.

Comment: Presumably, you mean to say "... the ***cardinality*** of (the set of) all continuous functions ... the ***cardinality*** of (the set of all) reals"

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different points to make here.

First of all, the notation "$\aleph_2$" is being horribly misused here (it reflects an implicit assumption of [the generalized continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis)). Leaving that aside, the claim you want to prove is actually **false**. That is:

- There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ (also denoted "$\beth_2$") many *arbitrary* functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$; by Cantor's theorem, $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}>2^{\aleph_0}$ and this latter (also called "$\beth_1$" or "$\mathfrak{c}$") is the cardinality of the continuum.
- However, there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ many *continuous* functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This is a standard exercise; one way to see it is to note that any continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is determined entirely by the set $$S_f=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^3: \vert f(a)-b\vert<c\}$$ *(that is, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous then $f=g$ iff $S_f=S_g$)* and then note that $\mathbb{Q}^3$ is countable so there only $2^{\aleph_0}$ many sets of rational triples at all *(strictly speaking this only shows that there are **at most** $2^{\aleph_0}$ continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but it's easy to show that's also a lower bound)*.

Finally, as to the step you mention, the point is that the meaning of cardinal exponentiation is *exactly* the size of the corresponding set of functions: $\kappa^\lambda$ is defined to be the cardinality of the set of functions from a set of cardinality $\lambda$ to a set of cardinality $\kappa$. So the set of all functions from reals to reals has cardinality $$(2^{\aleph_0})^{(2^{\aleph_0})}$$ since $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. *Note that here we're looking at the set of all functions, not just the continuous ones.*

It's then a basic result of set theory that the usual rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ holds for cardinal exponentiation, and that the product of two infinite cardinals is simply their maximum. So we get $$(2^{\aleph_0})^{2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$$ as Eric wrote.

Answer (score 0):

$Y^X$ is the space of *all* functions from $X\to Y$.

Furthermore,  $\lvert Y^X\rvert=\lvert Y\rvert ^{\lvert X\rvert}$.

Finally,  $\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$, since $2^{\aleph_0}$ has higher cardinality than $\aleph_0$.

So we arrive at $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, which is in fact not equal to $\aleph_2$ without making some additional assumptions...

Comment: $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is **not** $\aleph_2$ (at least, unless we assume [hypotheses beyond the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis)).

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing it out.  It's probably how he got the result though...

Comment: Oh it definitely is, but it's a big mistake on Gamow's part (and the comments/answers at the linked question go into this).

Comment: Ok.  I will edit.